# Apache Cassandra : nodetool-h localhost-p 7199 cfstats

Tags: cassandra

I start with cassandra and I want to know the size on disk of my column family. 
I search and I found the command : `nodetool-h localhost-p 7199 cfstats`

```
    Column Family: client
    SSTable count: 3
    Space used (live): 281774148
    Space used (total): 281774148
    Number of Keys (estimate): 1010176
    Memtable Columns Count: 0
    Memtable Data Size: 0
    Memtable Switch Count: 0
    Read Count: 0
    Read Latency: NaN ms.
    Write Count: 0
    Write Latency: NaN ms.
    Pending Tasks: 0
    Bloom Filter False Postives: 0
    Bloom Filter False Ratio: 0,00000
    Bloom Filter Space Used: 3752864
    Key cache capacity: 200000
    Key cache size: 0
    Key cache hit rate: NaN
    Row cache: disabled
    Compacted row minimum size: 216
    Compacted row maximum size: 310
    Compacted row mean size: 310
```

but I don't understand the result, so can you help me ?

Answer (score 3):

The actual amount of space being used is 'Space used (total)'.  This is measured in bytes.

The value of 'Space used (live)' is just for the files (SSTables) being used.  It may be less than 'Space used (total)' because, during compaction, there will be unused parts of files being merged that can't be deleted yet.  When a compaction finishes, it will be able to delete these duplicates and then 'Space used (total)' will decrease.

Note all these numbers are per node.  If you want total usage then sum the numbers up for the cfstats output on each node.

Comment: Thank you for answer  but can you explain why the SSTable count = 3 ??? what is the significance ???

Comment: That's the number of files your data is spread across.  It doesn't really matter - it will go up gradually as you insert more data.  And decrease when compactions complete.  You generally don't need to worry about it unless it is very large.

Comment: so, if my calcul is exact, the size of my column family = 33,59 Mo :( how is the benefit ??? because i inserted the same csv in Mysql i have = 7,5156 Mo !!!

Comment: No, the size is 281774148 bytes = 269 MB.

Comment: and if i would like to migrate 269 MB into Megaoctet so how i can calculate this please ???

Comment: Megabyte (MB)=Megaoctet (Mo) as far as I know.  Certainly the French Mo is the same as MB.

Comment: Conclusion :( I searched about the size and I conclude : MySQL(7 MB) is more performant than Cassandra (269 MB) !!! I expected the opposite :(